# Detect if a div with id including number is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My html code has X  elements, with their ids in this form:

```
viewer_mX
```

Here, X is a number from 1 to m (m can be different each time).

I want to use javascript to get the number X of the respective  element when somebody clicks one of these  elements.

I realise I should probably use a class (.viewer) and and id (#x) containing the number. However, I am using a library to generate the html  elements and I am stuck with this protocol and will have to make the best of it.

This is the javascript I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#viewer>...").click(function () {
    x = ...
    var number = x;
  });
});
```

What's missing in this code (indicated by 3 dots) is that viewer is not the full ID, but could be post-pended with something. I want to store whatever is after the clicked div in number, but I can't figure out which function to use for that.

Comment: Why not use class to identify elements and then data-attribute (data-id for example) and then get value of this data-attribute?

Comment: use a data attribute, so much easier...

Comment: Otherwise I would personally use $(this).attr('id').substr("viewer_m".length); No more magic needed :)

Comment: `I want to do in AJAX` ... what? You can do things in JavaScript, but not *in AJAX*!

Comment: Other way would be to use index i guess: `var number = $(this).index() + 1;`. But that's just bad workaround, instead use `data-*` attribute

Comment: I realise it would be easier and nicer to work with classes. However, sadly, I am stuck with this data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $("[id^='viewer_']").click(function () {
    var number = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not working though. I've already surrounded it with $(document).ready(function () {...} maybe something else is still wrong?

Comment: Oh, I was wrong in my question, it is an <a> element instead of a <div>. Would this cause an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use class to identify elements and then data-attribute for storing your id (data-id for example) and then get value of this data-attribute?

Otherwise I would personally use something like this

```
$(this).attr('id').substr("viewer_m".length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either split or a reg exp

```
var id = this.id.split("_m")[1]
```

or

```
var id = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

or better yet, use a data attribute

```
<div data-mid="123">
```

and reference it

```
$("[data-mid]").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).data("mid");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to this, as @Wax Cage mentioned, is to use classes and data attributes for better organizing. Example:

```
<div class="viewer" data-viewer-id="1">...</div>
```

---

```
$('.viewer').on('click', function() {
    var viewerId = $(this).data('viewerId');
    // ...
});
```